# How can I prevent user with full control permission on a subsite from adding a new app

Tags: permissions

Is that possible to customize full control permission on a subsite to such a way that user is prohibited from accessing "add an app"?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a custom permission level copied from full control permission level, remove the "Manage Lists" permission, and assign it to the user, this way he will be able to only create *subsites* or *pages* for that site.

Comment: Thanks! I've successfully removed the rights but there's a catch, I no longer have the right to edit links on current navigation. Is there a way to allow edit links as well as prohibiting user from accessing add an app.